# SQL Replace values in one cell if at least two defined values are in the cell

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, replace

I have a column/variable which I have to process. A cell of this column contains some values, for example, letters. If the cell contains at least two letters from a defined set of letters, say `abcd`, then all this specific letters should be replaced with `M`.

Here is a minimal example. string is the field to process, result should contain the processed string:

```
-- Table
CREATE TABLE x0 (
string    VARCHAR(255)
, result  VARCHAR(255)
);

-- Values (after values is the desired result)
INSERT INTO x0(string) VALUES 
  ('--a---')         -- '--a--'
, ('-c')             -- '-c'
, ('a-d')            -- 'M-'
, ('b--cd')          -- 'M--'
, ('--c---d')        -- '--M---'
;
```

This is my first try (which consider only `string` with an `a` to avoid too long code):

```
UPDATE x0 SET result = NULL;    
UPDATE x0
SET result = string
    , result = CASE WHEN string REGEXP 'a' AND string  NOT REGEXP '[bcd]' THEN result ELSE result END
    , result = CASE WHEN string REGEXP 'a' AND string  REGEXP '[bcd]' THEN REPLACE(result,'a','M') ELSE result END
    , result = CASE WHEN string REGEXP 'a' AND string  REGEXP '[bcd]' THEN REPLACE(result,'b','M') ELSE result  END 
    , result = CASE WHEN string REGEXP 'a' AND string  REGEXP '[bcd]' THEN REPLACE(result,'c','M') ELSE result  END
    , result = CASE WHEN string REGEXP 'a' AND string  REGEXP '[bcd]' THEN REPLACE(result,'d','M') ELSE result END
;
SELECT * FROM x0;
```

This is the result:

```
string  result
--a---  --a---
-c      -c
a-d     M-M
b--cd   b--cd
--c---d --c---d
```

I have two problems to solve:

1. My code is very specific and I have to write for each possible combination a `CASE WHEN`. Is there a clever way to do it for the general case?
2. When I get for each `abcd` a `M`, how can I remove all `M` but the first one?

Thanks for help.

---

Here is the long version of the code. Imagine the set consists not only of 4 letters but of 15.

```
UPDATE x0
SET result = string
    , result = CASE WHEN string REGEXP 'a' AND string  NOT REGEXP '[bcd]' THEN result ELSE result END
    , result = CASE WHEN string REGEXP 'a' AND string      REGEXP '[bcd]' THEN REPLACE(result,'a','M') ELSE result END
    , result = CASE WHEN string REGEXP 'a' AND string      REGEXP '[bcd]' THEN REPLACE(result,'b','M') ELSE result  END 
    , result = CASE WHEN string REGEXP 'a' AND string      REGEXP '[bcd]' THEN REPLACE(result,'c','M') ELSE result  END
    , result = CASE WHEN string REGEXP 'a' AND string      REGEXP '[bcd]' THEN REPLACE(result,'d','M') ELSE result END

    , result = CASE WHEN string REGEXP 'b' AND string  NOT REGEXP '[acd]' THEN result ELSE result END
    , result = CASE WHEN string REGEXP 'b' AND string      REGEXP '[acd]' THEN REPLACE(result,'a','M') ELSE result END
    , result = CASE WHEN string REGEXP 'b' AND string      REGEXP '[acd]' THEN REPLACE(result,'b','M') ELSE result  END 
    , result = CASE WHEN string REGEXP 'b' AND string      REGEXP '[acd]' THEN REPLACE(result,'c','M') ELSE result  END
    , result = CASE WHEN string REGEXP 'b' AND string      REGEXP '[acd]' THEN REPLACE(result,'d','M') ELSE result END

    , result = CASE WHEN string REGEXP 'c' AND string  NOT REGEXP '[abd]' THEN result ELSE result END
    , result = CASE WHEN string REGEXP 'c' AND string      REGEXP '[abd]' THEN REPLACE(result,'a','M') ELSE result END
    , result = CASE WHEN string REGEXP 'c' AND string      REGEXP '[abd]' THEN REPLACE(result,'b','M') ELSE result  END 
    , result = CASE WHEN string REGEXP 'c' AND string      REGEXP '[abd]' THEN REPLACE(result,'c','M') ELSE result  END
    , result = CASE WHEN string REGEXP 'c' AND string      REGEXP '[abd]' THEN REPLACE(result,'d','M') ELSE result END

    , result = CASE WHEN string REGEXP 'd' AND string  NOT REGEXP '[abc]' THEN result ELSE result END
    , result = CASE WHEN string REGEXP 'd' AND string      REGEXP '[abc]' THEN REPLACE(result,'a','M') ELSE result END
    , result = CASE WHEN string REGEXP 'd' AND string      REGEXP '[abc]' THEN REPLACE(result,'b','M') ELSE result  END 
    , result = CASE WHEN string REGEXP 'd' AND string      REGEXP '[abc]' THEN REPLACE(result,'c','M') ELSE result  END
    , result = CASE WHEN string REGEXP 'd' AND string      REGEXP '[abc]' THEN REPLACE(result,'d','M') ELSE result END

;
SELECT * FROM x0;

string  result
--a---  --a---
-c  -c
a-d     M-M
b--cd   M--MM
--c---d --M---M
```

Comment: The expected result for `--c---d` makes no sense to me given your rules.

Comment: @TomH "at least 2 letters from abcd", looks right to me

Comment: @AlexanderDerck Why is the example result `-M` instead of `--M---`?

Comment: @TomH oh the result, my bad, his results aren't correct for any of them with his rules...

Comment: @Tom H You're right. I didn't want to write the whole codes to keep it simple. The written code works only for the case where `string` has an `a`. @Tom H an d@Alexander Derck You'right both: it should be `--M---`.

Comment: I succeed to answer the second question: `result = CONCAT(SUBSTR(result,1,POSITION('M' IN result)),REPLACE(SUBSTR(result,POSITION('M' IN result)+1),'M',''))`.

Comment: Ideally, change your database structure. Don't store *multiple* values in a *single* "cell". This data should probably be spread across multiple rows with some (unseen as yet) columns providing any necessary correlation between the rows that are related.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Indeed. The original data were long-format (each value = letter was a single row) which I group_concat(distinct value). I don't think that the solution will be to distribute the values in the cell into several columns since one problem is that the number of values in the cell differs.

Comment: I didn't say several columns. I said several *rows*. I.e. if we had an additional `ID` column that tells us which rows belong together, then finding those sets with multiple values is as simple as `SELECT ID,COUNT(*) FROM Table where string in ('a','b','c','d') GROUP BY ID HAVING COUNT(*) > 1`. By treating the database as a spreadsheet (which it isn't) you're forcing yourself to use string manipulation rather than playing to the *strengths* of a relational database.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Sorry, you're right. The initial table was a long format where each id has has various rows with one value. The solution at the end should be a table with one id per row with a column result. I will look if I find a way like you suggested.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: At the end I came up with the following solution: (1) Replace lettes `abcd` with M. (2) Remove all M but one. (3) Add to each row from long table the value a or b or c or d if there was only one value (using HAVING) (4) Replace M with this value.

Comment: Some tasks are better done in a real programming language, not SQL.

Comment: See also the [REGEXP_REPLACE()](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/regexp_replace/) in MariaDB.

Comment: @RickJames Thanks. This would solve my problem but REGEXP_REPLACE works on MariaDB >= 10. I still have 5. You would suggest to export the table and using Perl or Python or another scripting language?

Comment: Perl , Python, PHP -- they are better at scripting this than SQL.

Answer (score 0):

I found a possible answer but still not perfect. First I add to each of the defined character a `M`. Then I count the `M`and if there are more then 1 than remove a,b,c,d.

```
UPDATE x0 SET result = NULL;
UPDATE x0
SET result = string
    , result = REPLACE(result,'a','Ma')
    , result = REPLACE(result,'b','Mb')
    , result = REPLACE(result,'c','Mc')
    , result = REPLACE(result,'d','Md')
, result = CASE 
           WHEN CHAR_LENGTH(result) - CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(result,'M','')) > 1 
       THEN REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(result,'a',''),'b',''),'c',''),'d','')
       ELSE REPLACE(result,'M','') END
    , result = CONCAT(SUBSTR(result,1,POSITION('M' IN result)),REPLACE(SUBSTR(result,POSITION('M' IN result)+1),'M',''))

;
SELECT * FROM x0;


string  result
--a---  --a---
-c      -c
a-d     M-
b--cd   M--
--c---d --M---
```

MariaDB version >= 10 has also function `REGEXP_REPLACE(subject, pattern, replace)` which would solve this kind of problems.